# How can I get HP Sleep and Charge to work?

Tags: windows-10, usb, sleep, charging

My laptop has a [USB 3.1 Gen 1 (HP Sleep and Charge)](https://store.hp.com/in-en/default/laptops-tablets/hp-pavilion-14-ce1001tx-5fw12pa.html) port, but I don't seem to be able to get it to work. The connected device stops charging when I put my PC to sleep, or turn it off.

I have already tried the solutions presented [here](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Software-and-How-To-Questions/Hp-laptop-sleep-mode-usb-phone-charge-problem/td-p/5699634) and [here](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Hp-sleep-and-charge/td-p/6915337):

- Disabled "Allow this computer to turn off this device to save power" from Device Manager for all USB controllers
- Disabled "USB selective suspend" from Power Options

There are no relevant settings in my BIOS. How can I get this feature to work? I am on the latest build of Windows 10.

Comment: On my Lenovo machine, that port works when turned off only if I keep the laptop plugged in. Do you have the laptop plugged into the AC outlet?  Then does that work?

Comment: @John Yep, doesn't work even if I have the laptop plugged in

Comment: You might wish to contact HP Support about the issue to see it they have a solution

Comment: @John Their website appears to be broken at the moment, at least in my locale.

Comment: HP Web Support say upgrading Sept 28 - 30 but HP Canada is up and running.  Try again later and good luck